# Difference between noverify and Xverify:none?

Tags: java, bytecode, jvm-arguments

What is the difference between the JVM arguments noverify and Xverify:none?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are the same.

`-X` represents a non-standard argument. Non-standard arguments only work for certain VMs (hence the name *non-standard*). `noverify` is simply a shortcut for `Xverify:none`.

Why have both? I don't think you'll get a real answer unless you asked the developers - it's not documented (as far as I can see). My best guess would be to stay consistent and to lower verbosity.

This is speculation, but reason for `noverify` existing could be based on how often developers use `-Xverify:true`. If verification is enabled by default, there's not much reason to use `-Xverify:true`, thus `-Xverify:false` would be the primary reason for using the `-Xverify` argument, hence the `noverify` shorthand.